# gfortran: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: gcc, makefile, fortran, gfortran

I am trying since a week to compile a code written in F90 and C. I keep getting an undefined symbols error. I will try to give as much information as I can but the package includes hundreds of files so it is a bit difficult to give all the details. This is the Makefile

```
include paths.mk
include include.mk.$(OPT)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#      Double check that the "LOWO" flags have been set.  In case they have not, clone the #
# standard options.  LOWO stands for LOWer Optimisation, and these flags are used for a    #
# subroutines that are taking several hours to compile with ifort-13 (ed_state_vars.f90    #
# and a few others).                                                                       #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
ifeq ($(F_LOWO_OPTS),)
   F_LOWO_OPTS = $(F_OPTS)
endif
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#



#----- Compiler commands. -----------------------------------------------------------------#
INCLUDES         = $(PAR_INCS) -I$(ED_INCS) $(HDF5_INCS) $(MPI_INCS) 
F90_COMMAND      = $(F_COMP) -c $(F_OPTS) $(INCLUDES) $(PAR_DEFS)
F90_LOWO_COMMAND = $(F_COMP) -c $(F_LOWO_OPTS) $(INCLUDES) $(PAR_DEFS)
FPP_COMMAND      = $(F_COMP) -c -DUSE_INTERF=$(USE_INTERF) -DUSENC=$(USENC) -D$(CMACH)     \
                   -DUSE_HDF5=$(USE_HDF5) -DUSE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO=$(USE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO)     \
                   -DUSE_MPIWTIME=$(USE_MPIWTIME) $(F_OPTS) $(INCLUDES) $(PAR_DEFS)
FPP_LOWO_COMMAND = $(F_COMP) -c -DUSE_INTERF=$(USE_INTERF) -DUSENC=$(USENC) -D$(CMACH)     \
                   -DUSE_HDF5=$(USE_HDF5) -DUSE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO=$(USE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO)     \
                   -DUSE_MPIWTIME=$(USE_MPIWTIME) $(F_LOWO_OPTS) $(INCLUDES) $(PAR_DEFS)
CXX_COMMAND      = $(C_COMP) -c $(C_OPTS) -D$(CMACH) $(HDF5_INCS) $(INCLUDES) $(PAR_DEFS)
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#


#----- Define archive and executable names. -----------------------------------------------#
EXE=$(BASE)/ed_$(ED_VERSION)-$(OPT)
LIBMODEL=$(BASE)/ed_$(ED_VERSION)-$(OPT).a
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

include objects.mk

#----- Define targets. --------------------------------------------------------------------#

all:
    make gendep
    make $(EXE)
    make $(EXE)
    make $(EXE)
    make $(EXE)
    make $(EXE)


gendep:
    @echo ""
    ./generate_deps.sh $(ED_ROOT)
    @echo === Finished dependencies ===

$(EXE): $(LIBMODEL) $(MAINOBJ) 
    @echo ""
    $(LOADER) -o $(EXE) edmain.o $(LOADER_OPTS) $(INCLUDES) $(LIBMODEL) $(HDF5_LIBS)   \
    $(PAR_LIBS) $(NC_LIBS) $(LIBS) $(LOADER_OPTS)
    @echo ""
    @echo Finished building === $(EXE)
    @echo ""

$(MAINOBJ):  $(MAIN) 
    @echo ""
    cp -f $< $(<F:.F90=.F90)
    $(FPP_COMMAND) $(<F:.F90=.F90)
    rm -f $(<F:.F90=.F90)

$(LIBMODEL): $(OBJ_MODEL)
    $(ARCHIVE) $(LIBMODEL) $(OBJ_MODEL)

FORCE: 

install:
    @echo ""
    ln -fs `pwd`/$(EXE) ../run/$(BASE)
    ln -fs `pwd`/$(EXE) ../test/$(BASE)
    @echo ""

clean:
    @echo ""
    rm -f $(LIBMODEL) $(EXE) *.o *.mod *.F90 *.f90 *.stb *.d dependency.mk 
    rm -f ../$(EXE) ../$(LIBMODEL)
    touch dependency.mk
    @echo ""

#----- Define rules -----------------------------------------------------------------------#
include rules.mk
```

The Makefile includes this other file

```
# Define make (gnu make works best).

MAKE=/usr/bin/make

# libraries.

BASE=$(ED_ROOT)/build/

# Activate appropriate parts below, comment out others.

# HDF 5  Libraries
# ED2 HAS OPTIONAL HDF 5 I/O
# If you wish to use this functionality specify USE_HDF5=1
# and specify the location of the include directory
# library files. Make sure you include the zlib.a location too.

USE_HDF5=1
HDF5_INCS=-I/opt/local/include
HDF5_LIBS= -L/opt/local/lib -lhdf5 -lhdf5_fortran -lz -L/opt/local/lib/libgcc/ -lstdc++ -lm

#---------------------------------------------------------------
# If you have a version of hdf5 compiled in parallel, then you
# may benefit from collective I/O, then use this flag = 1
# Otherwise, set it to zero.

USE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO=0

#---------------------------------------------------------------

# interface ----------------------------------------------------
# This should be 1 unless you are running with -gen-interfaces.
# Interfaces usually make the compilation to crash when the 
# -gen-interfaces option are on, so this flag bypass all 
# interfaces in the code.
USE_INTERF=1


# MPI_Wtime. ---------------------------------------------------
# If USE_MPIWTIME=1, then it will use MPI libraries to compute
# the wall time (the only double-precision intrinsic).  In case
# you don't have it, leave USE_MPIWTIME=0, in which case it will
# use a simpler, single-precision function.
USE_MPIWTIME=0


#-----------------  MAC_OS_X (Leopard) ---- gfortan/gcc ---------------
CMACH=MAC_OS_X
F_COMP=gfortran
C_COMP=gcc
LOADER=gfortran

##################################### COMPILER OPTIONS #####################################

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
USE_INTERF=1
F_OPTS= -O0 -ffree-line-length-none
C_OPTS= -O0 -DLITTLE -stdlib=libstdc++
F_LOWO_OPTS= -O0 -ffree-line-length-none
LOADER_OPTS= -O0 -ffixed-line-length-none
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# For IBM,HP,SGI,ALPHA,LINUX use these:
ARCHIVE=ar rs
# For NEC SX-6
#ARCHIVE=sxar rs
# For SUN,CONVEX
#ARCHIVE=ar r'
```

The compilation looks fine apart from a couple of warnings. Then in the linking phase something goes wrong. The last lines of the make read:

```
    ar rs /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build//ed_2.1-opt.a allometry.o an_header.o

    !!!all other object files listed!!!

therm_lib.o therm_lib8.o twostream_rad.o update_derived_props.o utils_c.o utils_f.o vegetation_dynamics.o

ar: creating archive /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build//ed_2.1-opt.a
    /opt/local/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build//ed_2.1-opt.a(consts_coms.o) has no symbols
    /opt/local/bin/ranlib: file: /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build//ed_2.1-opt.a(ed_max_dims.o) has no symbols

    cp -f /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/src/driver/edmain.F90 edmain.F90
    gfortran -c -DUSE_INTERF=1 -DUSENC= -DMAC_OS_X -DUSE_HDF5=1 -DUSE_COLLECTIVE_MPIO=0 -DUSE_MPIWTIME=0 -O0 -ffree-line-length-none  -I/Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/src/include -I/opt/local/include    edmain.F90
    rm -f edmain.F90

    gfortran -o /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build//ed_2.1-opt edmain.o -O0 -ffixed-line-length-none  -I/Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/src/include -I/opt/local/include   /Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build//ed_2.1-opt.a -L/opt/local/lib -lhdf5 -lhdf5_fortran -lz -L/opt/local/lib/libgcc/ -lstdc++ -lm   \
           -O0 -ffixed-line-length-none
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
      "_calchydrosubsurface_", referenced from:
          _ed_model_ in ed_2.1-opt.a(ed_model.o)
      "_calchydrosurface_", referenced from:
          _ed_model_ in ed_2.1-opt.a(ed_model.o)
      "_canopy_photosynthesis_", referenced from:
          ___rk4_driver_MOD_rk4_timestep in ed_2.1-opt.a(rk4_driver.o)


    !!!all other similar errors!!!


    "_writehydro_", referenced from:
          _ed_model_ in ed_2.1-opt.a(ed_model.o)
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make[1]: *** [/Users/manfredo/Desktop/ED2/ED/build//ed_2.1-opt] Error 1
    make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks

Comment: *I have read almost all pages regarding this type of error*: I'm absolutely sure you didn't, since there are definitely thousands of answers regarding linker problems like yours on StackOverflow alone. Also, your agressiveness reduces likelihood of people being willing to help you.

Answer (score 1):

That's a linker error. You don't seem to link in the .o file or library that contains `_calchydrosubsurface_`. Without knowing your source code or libraries used, it's hard to help you but tell you what to look for:

Search for the source code or library containing *calchydrosubsurface*; once found, make sure the symbol is exported properly (`nm <object file>`), and make sure you link against that in your make file.

Comment: nm -u ed_model.o gives me a list of all the undefined symbols and among them there is that `_calchydrosubsurface_` together with many others. How do I check that the symbol is exported properly?

Comment: In fact the subroutine is included in a file called lsm_hyd.f90 which looks fine. The compilation  of this file seems correct and a .o file is produced. Then if i type `nm -u lsm_hyd.o` I read `0000000000007141 T ___lsm_hyd_MOD_calchydrosubsurface`

Comment: `T` is a good sign. However, `___lsm_hyd_MOD_calchydrosubsurface != _calchydrosubsurface_`. I really don't know how to progress further from here -- gfortran linking has always been a bit special.

Comment: Looks to me a little bit as if the routine is defined in a module (lsm_hyd) and that the calling routine does not have the appropriate use statement.